# Object slicing with base class vector and derived class pointers

Tags: c++

Here is a simplified version of my scenario:

```
class Base
{
    class Entry
    {
        ...
    }

    std::vector<Entry *> entryList;

    void processEntry() = 0;

    void OnProcessEntry(); // processEntry callback
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    class Entry : public Base::Entry
    {
        ...
    }

    void processEntry() 
    {
         ...
         entryList.push_back(new Entry); 
         OnProcessEntry();
    }
};
```

When I copy a `Derived::Entry` pointer into `entryList`, the object is sliced to `Base::Entry`. Is there any way I can get the Entry back to its original "unsliced" state within the base class method `OnProcessEntry`?

If anybody can recommend a more appropriate title please do and I will edit.

Thanks.

Comment: "When I copy a Derived::Entry pointer into entryList, the object is sliced to Base::Entry" why do you think so? You should reread what object slicing is. It appears with objects. Pointers dont slice.

Comment: If you have some code with an actual problem, then you should show that. There is no problem in the example you posted here.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Because when I look at the pointers inside `entryList` when debugging, I can no longer see the members exclusive to Derived::Entry, only the base members. If that isn't slicing, then what is it?

Comment: thats not slicing, thats the interface you can access via a `Base` pointer. The data is still there (not sure how to see it with a debugger though). Cast the pointer to `Derived*` and you can access also `Derived`s members

Comment: Get a better debugger?

Comment: please try to include such information in the question. It appears that your actual question/problem is that your debugger shows you only `Base` interface for a `Base` pointer, but thats actually not a big surprise...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I see, that's very interesting. I didn't know that and hopefully you can see why I made the incorrect assumption. Thank you for teaching me something. :)

Comment: i will flag this as a duplicate, it is not really the same question, but it explains why your premise is broken, if you want a dedicated answer, please fix your questin to include why you think your code has a problem / what is the actual "problem" you want to fix

Comment: Ok. I was thinking maybe I should delete the question. Do you think it is better that I edit to include what lead me to think what I did and keep it up?

Comment: @notanalien You probably should explain the whole story regarding your debug observations in your question title and body.